# Structured Logging in Azure Functions

Tags: logging, azure-functions, structured-logging

i am trying to get structured logging working in a Azure Function, but it does not work on my side.

I wrote a simple application like this

```
[FunctionName("Dummy")]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequest request, ILogger log)
{
    var instance = new User
    {
        Name1 = "foo",
        Name2 = "bar"
    };
    log.LogInformation("Test1: {$Test}", instance);
    log.LogInformation("Test2: {@Name}", instance);
    log.LogInformation("Test3: {@Name}", new { Name1 = "abc", Name2 = "def" });
    log.LogInformation("Test4: {Vorname} {Nachname}", instance.Name1, instance.Name2);
    return new OkResult();
}

public class User
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

and the output looks like this:

```
Test1: Company.FunctionApp1.Function+User
Test2: Company.FunctionApp1.Function+User
Test3: { Name1 = abc, Name2 = def }
Test4: foo bar
```

I have no clue why the destructure is working on the dynamic type but not on the defined class. I have found many examples for normal logging with no destructure of a object, but i thought that it should work out of the box.

Am i missing something?

Comment: What do you want as result ?

Comment: I want the same result between Test2 and Test3. Like in this example => https://github.com/messagetemplates/messagetemplates-csharp

I thought that this would be the default templating of the .Net Core Logger

Comment: Does this code: `log.LogInformation("Test1: {$Test}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance));` meet your requirement ?

Comment: Yes, this would work, but i thought that this kind of behavior is implemented in the default logger.

Comment: I'm not sure if it being supported by Application Insights provider. Note - SeriLog provide destructuring the object while logging. Currently the workaround can be for you is to define the ToString on `User` object. Or you can write an extension method which can use the reflection to destructure the object.

Comment: I thought of this because it is stated so on this site => https://messagetemplates.org/ but maybe it is not implemented in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Test 3 is printing as `{ Name1 = abc, Name2 = def }` as the type defined is as anonymous object for which compiler generates the `ToString()` method to return a string with property and value mapping.

Check in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2516) discussion.

You can validate the same by decompiling.

Since, Test2 and Test1 uses object and for which there is no override `ToString()` definition that's why the TypeName is returned.

The right way would be to go with Test4 so that `Vorname` and `Nachname` are logged as custom property and can be used to filter.

Comment: Good point with the dynamic type, i have missed this. I do want it to be as custom properties in application insights. And it does work with the JsonConvert.SerializeObject, but in my opinion it should work out of the box with the @ in front of the name.

I thought that the default implementation is according to this https://messagetemplates.org/

Answer (score 0):

user1672994's answer is right, you can do something like below:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp96
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var instance = new User
            {
                Name1 = "foo",
                Name2 = "bar"
            };
            log.LogInformation("Test1: {$Test}", instance);
            log.LogInformation("Test2: {@Name}", instance);
            log.LogInformation("Test3: {@Name}", new { Name1 = "abc", Name2 = "def" });
            log.LogInformation("Test4: {Vorname} {Nachname}", instance.Name1, instance.Name2);
            return new OkObjectResult("");
        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = "{ Name1 = " + Name1 + ", Name2 =" + Name2 + " }";
            return str;
        }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And you will get:

[image]